# How to find that the content is truncated?

Tags: django, truncate

I'm trying to build a blog app and the problem is when I use tag 'truncatewords_html' in my template to truncate posts longer than specified number of words, I need to link to complete post by some title like 'read more...' after truncation. So I should know that the post was truncated or not.

P.S.: Is this a pythonic way to solve the problem?

```
{% ifequal post.body|length post.body|truncatewords_html:max_words|length %}
  {{ post.body|safe }}
{% else %}
  {{ post.body|truncatewords_html:max_words|safe }}<a href="{{ post.url}}">read more</a>
{% endifequal %}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty convoluted but django has some weird corners. Basically I figure if the string length is the same if you truncate at x and x+1 words then the string has not been truncated...

```
{% ifnotequal post.body|truncatewords_html:30|length post.body|truncatewords_html:31|length %}
   <a href="#">read more...</a>
{% endifnotequal %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom template tag (see [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)), or manually check in the template, whether the content you want to display exceeds the given length via [`length`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#length) builtin filter.

Comment: +1 for the simple method of checking whether the display exceeds the length. Simple, and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to personal preference, but for my taste you're doing way too much work in the template. I would create a method on the Post model, `read_more_needed()` perhaps, which returns True or False depending on the length of the text. eg:

```
def read_more_needed(self):
    from django.utils.text import truncate_html_words
    return not truncate_html_words(self.body,30)==truncate_html_words(self.body,31)
```

Then your template would read:

```
{% if post.read_more_needed %}
  {{ post.body|truncatewords_html:30|safe }}<a href="{{ post.url}}">read more</a>
{% else %}
  {{ post.body|safe }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If you're going to add "read_more_need()" to the model, then you should be doing the truncation in the model also.  The same code doing the truncation should determine if the content has been truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6799

This patch provides a method to replace the default elipses for truncated text.